# Using Quartz in a Nancyfx project. Do not have global.asax where start schedule?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, quartz-scheduler, nancy, bootstrapper

I have a very simple schedule and a job using Quartz and it works fine when I am NOT using nancyfx and I have `MySchedule.Start()` in my global.asax. I tried same job same schedule in a separate MVC project which uses nancyfx and bootstrapper.cs and I am not sure where to run `MySchedule.Start()`

I tried it within bootstrapper and it did not work:

```
public class Bootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ApplicationStartup(Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer container, Nancy.Bootstrapper.IPipelines pipelines)
    {
        base.ApplicationStartup(container, pipelines);
        MySchedule.Start();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you use ASP.NET MVC with NancyFX? Nancy is already an API layer for your C# application. I prefer creating a console application, use topshelf in main and start nancy (self host) and quartz job at the same time when service is started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application startup run only when any of the NancyFx routes are invoked meaning that your scheduler will only start after receiving a request to the api. I suggest using Owin and putting the starting of the scheduler in the StartUp.cs class that would give you an equivalent of Global.asax.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't seem to be working: `public static void Configuration(IAppBuilder app){ MySchedule.Start(); }`

Comment: The two references: 
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb 
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost

Comment: Alright I fixed it.. you will need Own:AutomaticAppstart in the config.